# Algoritmo de infija a postfija/prefija es erróneo

Tags: algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, matemáticas, pilas

He hecho las pruebas de escritorio para ambos algoritmos (prefija y postfija) y llegue a la conclusión de que los algoritmos deben de estar mal hechos (yo no los hice :). Los probé con esta expresión infija: `(4+3)*5`.

El resultado de la prueba de escritorio de prefija es: `*)3+4435` y no `*+435`.

El resultado de la prueba de escritorio de postfija es: `5+3(4` y no `43+5*`.

Estan mal planteados los algoritmos? O yo los aplique mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos el código que has realizado? De esa manera podremos ver si tu traducción es la responsable de que no te funcione como se espera, o realmente es el algoritmo lo que está mal implementado. Gracias.

Comment: te refieres a la prueba de escritorio? es una tabla que dibuje, yo creo que sera complicado pasarla a codigo aqui @JoséManuelRamos

Comment: Probaste a crearlo en un lenguaje de programación?

Comment: No, no lo hice @NaCl